# how do i store Google Authenticated user Profile picture to firebase Database or Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

[Image View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnLbi.png)     <<<i could save the email, display name and the provider but how do i store the user image or profile picture. the code that i have implemented to save few details of the user

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
DatabaseReference users = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
users.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("Email").setValue(user.getEmail());
users.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("Fullname").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
users.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("Provider").setValue(user.getProviderId());
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeACTIVITY.class));
       finish();
```

Comment: Please show where you get profile picture of user ?

Comment: i dont know how to save a profile picture. i am trying to save the details of the user from the login activity